# How to let users register with their Facebook accounts?

Tags: 7, users, social-network

I would like to let visitors choose between signing up by using Drupal's core sign-up system, or to register using their Facebook account.

I looked at a few Facebook related modules but that was a little confusing, and I couldn't make up my mind on which one to use (I don't use Facebook myself so I guess that doesn't help).

What are the differences between regular registered users and those who signed up using their Facebook account?
Will Drupal have access to their emails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried out all of the current suggestions, have used both [Drupal for Facebook](http://drupal.org/project/fb) and [FBConnect](http://drupal.org/project/fbconnect) on sites in non-trivial ways, and only pain lies down those roads.

If all you need is authentication and maybe a few imported user profile fields (such as e-mail) go with [FBOauth](http://drupal.org/project/fboauth). Its newer, but is far easier to set up and use, and far easier to build off of if you're not trying anything too extraordinary.

The relationship between regular users and Facebook users depends a lot on the module you pick. In general all the modules create a table that associates FB ids with drupal user ids. How that happens varies widely. If you need a lot of flexibility in terms of account linking [FBConnect](http://drupal.org/project/fbconnect) is pretty full featured in that area but tends to be buggy elsewhere.

Comment: For D7, FBOauth is the way to go. I've recently tried a few of the modules, and it's by far the easiest to set up and configure, and it just works, as opposed to the other ones, which can be very hard to get working in my experience.

Comment: Ok so I will give it a try since the other ones seem to be 'too much'.

Thanks to everyone

Comment: A few tips to be aware of that might 'trip you up' if you find that you can log in but other people can't: Take the associated Facebook app you would create for login out of sandbox mode: https://drupal.org/node/1858824#comment-7073788
Check country restriction settings: https://drupal.org/node/1850544

Comment: Just got Drupal for Facebook working - I've taken some screenshots and will try to write up for you as soon as I can. Give me a nudge with a comment if I forget.

Answer (score 5):

[Drupal for FaceBook](http://drupal.org/project/fb) is the one you need.

You can configure application settings and which information you want to get from users, such as email address.

Unlike other suggestions, this module does not rely on third party providers and registrations other than Facebook.

Comment: This answer doesn't help much at all so I am a little puzzled at to why this was upvoted 4 times (by the way I would not downvote) Presumably those 4 voters and @Ivanhoe123 have each used [Drupal for Facebook](http://drupal.org/project/fb) successfully to provide registration and login on a Drupal site. If so then, care to share a step-by-step guide for using rather than merely stating the module's existence that it is possible. The original poster of the question already stated that they have looked at some modules, perhaps [Drupal for Facebook](http://drupal.org/project/fb) was one of them.

Comment: Moreover, the read me files, e.g. `help/fb_connect/README.txt` files that accompany [Drupal For Facebook](http://drupal.org/project/fb) just state some basic setup and then various unrelated things you can do. A *recipe* step-by-step guide would have been very helpful. If I ever figure out how to use this module I would be more than happy to write a precises step-by-step guide myself.

Comment: Also, can you explain what you mean by "third party providers and registrations" and what "other suggestions" here use these?

Comment: Just got Drupal for Facebook working - I've taken some screenshots and will try to write up as soon as I can. A nice, lovely, precise step-by-step guide! Do give me a nudge with a comment if I forget.

Answer (score 2):

[Facebook Connect](http://drupal.org/project/fbconnect) works out of the box. I have been using it in a couple of sites.

Comment: +1 yes a nice module, I've got it working too. One thing I particularly like is the mapping it provides of your facebook user data to populate your Drupal user account. I've also got Drupal for Facebook working too - and one advantage I can see that it has over Facebook Connect is that Drupal for Facebook *can be set up* detect if you've created an ordinary Drupal account in the past and if you then login with Facebook it will obtain the email account associated with that Facebook account and if it matches the original account, it logs you in as that account and connects the two, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Use this module [Drupal Janrain](http://drupal.org/project/rpx)

You can even get different user information from the social media account depending on his privacy.

Answer (score 0):

I've been a fan of Simple FB Connect which hasn't been mentioned. It's fairly new and it relies on Facebook's PHP SDK so hopefully the team will be able to keep up with API changes. Here's a [tutorial for Drupal Facebook login](http://www.daymuse.com/blogs/drupal-facebook-login-connect-integration-tutorial) using Simple FB Connect and a roundup of related solutions. FBOAuth, mentioned, is also a good solution.

Ultimately, the trouble with these third party logins is keeping your integration updated with constant API changes from the third party.

Answer (score 0):

Simple FB Connect module allows users to register and login to your Drupal site with their Facebook account.
and they provide both choice login through website and login through facebook. And you can find more details through [login with Facebook](http://www.daymuse.com/blogs/drupal-facebook-login-connect-integration-tutorial) link.